# divorcing free proxy service from client

Tags: proxy

http://ultrareach.com is the free proxy service I use to access the web. Its comes in two parts: the client and the service. Is there any way that I can dissect the client to see whether it uses any type of standard protocol to connect to the servers? I would like to be able to access the service from another client, specifically one that would run on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you describe might break the license terms of the software+service.

use network sniffer [ eg [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ] to analyze communication between client software and another tunnel endpoint. since they mention encryption - it will be quite a difficult job...

Comment: can you please be more specific/give me more details and pointers on how to go about this?

you say *difficult*.  How dificult?

Comment: If it use encryption difficult mean near impossible

Comment: difficult as in 'non-trivial problem' [ sometimes heard on university lectures, that actually translates into: forget, or hire bunch of russian/israeli/chinese hackers to reverse engineer the binaries and understand what encryption is used, how keys are stored / exchanged etc ].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it under WINE in LINUX? Lots of Windows apps. will run this way. Would certainly be easier than trying to reverse engineer and re-write their client.